# What it means by saying"definite medical applications"

Tags: meaning-in-context, paraphrasing

> Nanomedicine is defined by the US National Institute of health as "the science that uses nanomaterials for the progress of analysis, treatment and hindrance of **definite medical applications**".

What does it Mean by medical applications and being definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to specific and well-defined uses of nanomedicine in the field of healthcare. It implies that nanomaterials are employed for specific purposes such as diagnosis, treatment, and prevention of targeted medical conditions, as opposed to general or broad applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means "specific medical applications", or "certain medical applications". That's a very unusual way to use the word definite though.

Comment: And _medical applications_ are uses of something for medical treatment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).